# How to show element when mouseenter on parent?

Tags: javascript, html, events, jquery-selectors

I have list:

```
<ul class="items">
    <li class="item">
         <div>Test</div>
         <div class="control" hidden="true">Visible</div>
         <ul class="items">
             <li class="item">
                 <div>Test1</div>
                 <div class="control" hidden="true">Visible</div>
             </li>
             <li class="item">
                 <div>Test2</div>
                 <div class="control" hidden="true">Visible</div>
             </li>
             <li class="item">
                 <div>Test3</div>
                 <div class="control" hidden="true">Visible</div>
             </li>
         </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
         <div>Test4</div>
         <div class="control" hidden="true">Visible</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying

```
'mouseenter li.item': function (event) {
    $(event.currentTarget).find('div.control').show();
}
```

But it works on all children div with class 'control'. Can you please help me? I think

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+jquery+get+only+direct+children+instead+of+all+descendants&gws_rd=ssl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`.find()` method](https://api.jquery.com/find/) will find *all* matching descendant elements.

If you only want to select direct children, use the [`.children()` method](https://api.jquery.com/children/) instead:

```
$(event.currentTarget).children('div.control').show();
```

Alternatively, you can also use the [direct child selector, `>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators):

```
$(event.currentTarget).find('> div.control').show();
```